# Determine the reflection $z^{*}$ of $z$ across the parabola $y=x^2$. Expand $z^{*}$ into a power series in powers of $\bar{z}$...

Tags: complex-analysis, reflection

> Determine the reflection $z^{*}$ of $z$ across the parabola $y=x^2$. Expand $z^{*}$ into a power series in powers of $\bar{z}$...

I'm not looking for a complete solution, of course, because I genuinely *don't know what the question is asking.* This is Exercise 10.3.5 in Gamelin's "Complex Analysis" on the Schwarz Reflection Principle. Can someone give me a little bit of a push to start the question, and maybe some geometric intuition as to what's happening here? There's probably a purely algebraic way to do this but I want to get some intuition on this. I do not have an "attempt" as per the guidelines because I genuinely don't know where to start. If someone could give me a push in the right direction and maybe explain a little bit of the geometric ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (algebraic) idea is to write the analytic curve (in this case the parabola $y=x^2$) as an equation in $z$ and $\bar{z}$, and solve it in the form $z=f(\bar{z})$ with an analytic function $f$. Since it is known that the analytic reflection is of the form $g(\bar{z})$ with an analytic function $g$, and since $f$ and $g$ agree on the complex conjugate of the curve, by the uniqueness principle you must have $f=g$, i.e., the original equation of the curve also gives you the reflection.

In the simple case of a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$, it works as follows: Rewrite as $z\bar{z} = r^2$, solve for $z$ as $z = r^2/\bar{z}$, so the reflection is given by $z \mapsto r^2/\bar{z}$. In more complicated cases, solving the equation explicitly for $z$ might not be possible, but you should always be able to get as many derivatives at some point on the curve by implicit differentiation, or maybe some sort of series expansion.

Comment: Your answer is algebraic. Could you give some geometric intuition as to what's going on? Aren't we *actually* projecting the curve $y=x^2$ across the real axis, and then projecting over that, since its obvious? Furthermore, the map $z\to \frac{r^2}{\bar{z}}$ is the identity map, so I am not convinced this works. Thanks. I've upvoted for the response, and will accept if given this explanation.

Comment: I am not sure that I can give a good geometric intuition, since analytic reflection is intrinsically quite analytic. (Though for a parabola there should be a geometric interpretation, probably with some dual family of conic sections.) What kind of projection do you mean? I don't see a canonical projection. (Again, maybe this could be done along a dual family of conical sections in this example.) And in the circle example the given map is only the identity on the circle, not inside or outside of it (which is exactly what reflection does.)